# How to find missing index details of a Database in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was working with SQL server and lately started working with PostgreSQL.The database queries in PostgreSQL seems very slow as it has not much indices on it's tables, so i thought of creating necessary indices .

In SQL server i'm using the below query to identify the most impacted indices.Is there any such query or method in PostgreSQL for finding the missing indices.How can i find which all indices need to be created on tables?

**SQL Server Missing index query using DMV**

```
SELECT TOP 25
dm_mid.database_id AS DatabaseID,
dm_migs.avg_user_impact*(dm_migs.user_seeks+dm_migs.user_scans) Avg_Estimated_Impact,
dm_migs.last_user_seek AS Last_User_Seek,
OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) AS [TableName],
'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) + '_'
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.equality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','') 
+ CASE
WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL
AND dm_mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN '_'
ELSE ''
END
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.inequality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','')
+ ']'
+ ' ON ' + dm_mid.statement
+ ' (' + ISNULL (dm_mid.equality_columns,'')
+ CASE WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND dm_mid.inequality_columns 
IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE
'' END
+ ISNULL (dm_mid.inequality_columns, '')
+ ')'
+ ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + dm_mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS Create_Statement
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups dm_mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats dm_migs
ON dm_migs.group_handle = dm_mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details dm_mid
ON dm_mig.index_handle = dm_mid.index_handle
WHERE dm_mid.database_ID = DB_ID()
ORDER BY Avg_Estimated_Impact DESC
GO
```

Comment: You need to explain what that messy SQL actually does. What information does it extract? There is nothing built-in in Postgres to suggest missing indexes, but the extension [pg_qualstats](https://github.com/powa-team/pg_qualstats) can be used to [suggest missing indexes](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/22/automatic-index-recommendations-in-postgresql-using-pg_qualstats-and-hypopg/)

Comment: I think the better approach is to look at the slow queries one by one. I find that very often queries migrated from other DBMS products do not use the full power of Postgres or use an approach that might be good for the old DBMS, but is not the right way of doing things in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please post this as an answer,gonna implement the pg_qualstats extension.I do have fw slow running queries,so i thought if i get a list of missing indices as in MS SQL then it will be really helpful for the performance tuning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question with the comment from a_horse_with_no_name

""You need to explain what that messy SQL actually does. What information does it extract? There is nothing built-in in Postgres to suggest missing indexes, but the extension pg_qualstats can be used to suggest missing indexes
"

Using pg_qualstats resolved this situation.